# Novel where main character discovers dragons hidden in castle?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I found this book at a used book store in America sometime around 2005. From what I remember of the style of the cover (and the general condition), I would assumed it was published sometime 1985-2005.

It's medieval-esque fantasy. The main character is a young woman who comes to work at a castle. At first, the lord of the castle is aloof and cold with her. Then, while exploring the castle, she finds a dungeon containing dragons. The lord had hidden them from her to keep them safe.

I think that the word of the dragons gets out and people come to attack the castle. The climax of the novel has the main character and the lord of the castle defending the castle against attackers.

There is also a romance between the main character and the lord, though the book isn't primarily a romance novel.

I believe the cover of the edition I had was a picture of the castle. The colors were blues and greys. I also think that the title was the name of the castle, which had the word "Dragon" in it. I think the author was a woman.

Comment: The Secret of Dragonhome by John Peel is worth a look.

Comment: @Frock Yes, that's it! Care to make it an answer so I can accept?